# Formatting Strings Given Place Holders

Tags: python

I have to replace certain placeholders with variables from a list, however I am unsure about how to reformat the placeholders.

```
warning = 'I don\'t recognize the name {0}. Did you mean {1}?'
```

The above line of code is what I need to reformat. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a default Python formatting string, it can be used with `format`.

```
>>> warning = 'I don\'t recognize the name {0}. Did you mean {1}?'
>>> warning.format("Meliodus123", "format")
"I don't recognize the name Meliodus123. Did you mean format?"
```

The number in `{0}` represent the argument position passed to `format`.